# ASP.NET MVC 3 and NHibernate Scaffolding

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I found this article [http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/], which explains how to use MVC Scaffolding with one-to-many relationships in EF to create a listbox with an enumerated collection as the choice.

I tried using this with my project, but I have run into a problem - I don't want to use EF (or include a reference to it). I am using POCOs which are then mapped using a repository pattern and persisted using NHibernate.

Is there a way to create the same scaffolding listboxes for POCOs without having to create the DataContext which the article created.

**Edit:** I do know how to do this manually, I am looking for a way for the scaffold code to do this for me.

Comment: Did you find anything on this? I'm looking for the same and couldn't find anything. Thanks

Comment: No there were no out of the box solutions - I am looking at making some though and I will put them on codeplex if/when.

Comment: Is there a currently active framework/tool for asp.net scaffolding around an EF or nhibernate object set?  I am looking for one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the post on [Overriding T4 Templates](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) from the same series should tell you all you need to know to switch to a repository template based on NHibernate.  If you end up implementing your own, please post them somewhere :)

Comment: I'll release them if I get around to making them. Thanks.

Comment: @Macropus did you ever get around to releasing them ?

Comment: I made some very very simple ones but never released them. I will dig them out and see if they are good enough to stick up on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a project, that tried to implement templates for NHibernate and MVC scaffolding, but  according to [this thread](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/discussions/241934) it seems to be closed.